# How to implement parser for a grammar in Java

Tags: parsing, nlp

I have defined a grammar and now I'm implementing a parser for it.

The program should start with the keyword **main** followed by an opening curly bracket, followed in turn by a (possibly empty) sequence of statements, and terminated by a closing curly bracket. My questions is how to define the program in the parser? I have tried several different ways, including this, but it doesn't seem to be correct when I test.

```
public void program() {
        //Program -> MAIN LCBR Statement* RCBR
        eat("MAIN");
        eat("LCBR");
       while (lex.token().type != "RCBR") {
            statement();
       }
    }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You presumably need an `eat("RCBR");` after the while-loop. But you haven't provided enough info to know if that's your problem. What happens when you test? Can your parser at least handle a Program with no Statements?